# onclicklistener for ui change does not update on first click

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, buttonclick

I have an issue where I am trying to change the foreground of a Button upon a click event. The foreground only changes after the first click.

```
public void muteSoundClick(View view){
        playSound = preferences.getBoolean("playSound", true);

        if (playSound) {
            view.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.foreground_padding_unmute));
            editor.putBoolean("playSound", false);
            editor.apply();
        }
        else {
            view.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.foreground_padding_mute));
            editor.putBoolean("playSound", true);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
```

I retrieve a variable from the android SharedPrefernces, which i use to determine which foreground to use.

Comment: can you log inside the playSound if condition and post what the log shows you ?

Comment: What data do you suggest I log? The condition works as expected and the flows ends up in the correct statements, however the UI does not change on the first click.

Comment: if it doesn't change then the onClick is not assigned 
check in your xml in your button component that you are assiging onClick attribute to muteSoundClick method
`android:onClick="muteSoundClick"`

Comment: Background or Foreground?

Comment: @HossamEldeenOnsy onClick is assigned in the xml, like I said it's only the first time clicked that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Toaster yes Foreground* my bad

Comment: @FFGH , You have used `setForeground()` but want to change background ?

Comment: @Toaster I created the post, i am indeed trying to change the foreground. Edited my post just now.

Comment: @FFGH my bad sorry.

Comment: check the answer now and confirm it with your activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to check playsound at the start of the activity so that the button itself would get what you are saving the first time so you need something like this :

```
    playSound = preferences.getBoolean("playSound", true);

    if(playSound)
        button.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.foreground_padding_mute));
    else

     button.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.foreground_padding_unmute));
```

Then you can handle the clicks using the same method you have posted in your question

here is a sample example activity to sum it up :

```
public class SimpleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
boolean playSound;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    Button button = findViewById(YourButtonID);
        playSound = preferences.getBoolean("playSound", true);

        if(playSound)
            button.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.foreground_padding_mute));
        else
            button.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.foreground_padding_unmute));

}


public void muteSoundClick(View view){
    playSound = preferences.getBoolean("playSound", true);

    if (playSound) {
        view.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.foreground_padding_unmute));
        editor.putBoolean("playSound", false);
        editor.apply();
    }
    else {
        view.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.foreground_padding_mute));
        editor.putBoolean("playSound", true);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this is exactly what I have at the moment.. Which does not work for me. Does this work when you run it?

Comment: yes and i added now this line to confirm the editor
`editor= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();`

are you sure that this is a Button and you are using API 23+ ?

Comment: Yes I'm on API 24 and it is a Button. Still does not work for me, so crazy.

Comment: and when you log inside the function and in the conditions they work fine without a problem after the first click right ?

Comment: Even on the first click the function works fine. So .setForeground gets called normally even on the first click. Only the UI change does not happen on the first click.

Comment: I am an idiot, it's solved. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you aren't really editing the preferences. Like this.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public void muteSoundClick(View view){
    playSound = preferences.getBoolean("playSound", true);

    if (playSound) {
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        view.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.foreground_padding_unmute));
        editor.putBoolean("playSound", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else {
        view.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.foreground_padding_mute));
        editor.putBoolean("playSound", true);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: The preferences do indeed change when clicked, even on the first click. It's only the UI that does not update on the first click.